# IBM blockchain platform VS code extension - unable to create new new Fabric environment/wallets

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, platform

Following the tutorials listed in https://github.com/HyperledgerHandsOn/trade-network, I was able to create a trade network and connect to it. However, after a VS code restart, all the created FAbric environments and wallets disappeared. Additionally, I am unable to recreate them.
Upon trying to manually add the Fabric environments/wallets am trying to add a new Fabric environment the "+" sign does not works (unresponsive) nor does an option appear after right clicks.

Tried giving the extension a reinstall but no luck:-

[image]

Additionally, I see weird errors when trying to run the extension commands on VS code pallet - for example this is what I see when I run a "View Prerequisite" command -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by downgrading the version. Looks like this is an error with version 2.0.4.